# Is there a way to open screen's terminal scrollback buffer in vim?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I'm looking for a way to drop the mouse, forever and always. I got to a very comfortable point, where I don't use it for regular text editing, however, something's bothering me. 
When I work with the shell and I want to copy some prev output, I need to highlight + copy using the mouse. That sucks. I know about `screen` and 'Ctrl-A [', is cool, but I want to browse the scrollback in Vim, not in Screen's built-in interface.

Is there a way for me to open the current shell output buffer into Vim and copy from it?

Comment: There's no such thing as a “shell scrollback buffer”, [that's a feature of the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con). Are you running your shell inside screen or not? If not, in what terminal emulator? What do you mean by “screen just lets me use a old simple vi” — I don't see what screen has to do with what software you can use?

Comment: @Gilles You're right of course, I modified the title. I've always been confused about where's what implemented in the relation between terminal and shell. I run iTerm. I'm ready to use `screen` as well. Is not 'vi' per see I think, but if you use screen an `Ctrl-A` + `[` you can copy from the scrollback, however, you're in a `vi`-like editor, without the power of vim + plugins.

Comment: Oh, I see. When you use `Ctrl-A [`, you're still in Screen, this has nothing to do with Vi except that a couple of key bindings are inspired from vi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From within a Screen window, run

```
screen -X hardcopy -h s
vim s
rm s
```

`hardcopy -h` dumps the scrollback into a temporary file which you can then open in Vim if you like. If you script this you should use a proper temporary file name:

```
#!/bin/sh
scrollback_file=$(mktemp)
screen -X hardcopy -h "$scrollback_file"
vim -c 'call delete(@%)' "$scrollback_file"
```

(Or you could just run your shell in Emacs or in Neovim.)

Comment: Ty, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running the command again, you can always do

```bsh
<command> | vim -
```

If you also care about `stderr`:

```bsh
<command> 2>&1 | vim -
```

Specially useful if you want to search for a pattern and open vim in that location:

```bsh
grep -iIrHn <pattern> | vim -
```

then place the cursor at the line line of the pattern and press `gF`

Comment: About `grep .. | vim`: That's a roundabout way of doing `:grep ...` and then using [the quickfix list](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html?#quickfix).